# when to use offset-3 in bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i read a article from here http://victorshi.com/blog/post/How-to-make-a-div-center-in-Bootstrap3 that how to center a div when using bootstrap framework.

their code

```
<div class="row">  
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">center</div>  
</div>
```

i just like to know why they use col-lg-offset-3 ? why they did not use col-lg-offset-2 or col-lg-offset-4 etc.

please guide me about the above code sample. thanks

Comment: the offset number "technically" counts as a used div. So in their case a "real" col-6 would require a col-3 on each side to equal the required 12 columns per row. Similarly you could have a "real" col-8 of content which would require a col-2 on either side to get you to 12 columns per row. Does that make sense? You don't have to put them on the right side of your content div but for sake of explaining using the 12 column bootstrap grid it's easier to think of it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`col-lg-6` is a div with width 6 columns (out of 12). The `col-lg-offset-3` pushes the div 3 columns to the right. In this case, the `row` displays a div of half width (6/12 columns) in the center of the div (3/12 pushes 6/12 to the middle).

All of this is documented very well [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). I would encourage you to read the documentation and experiment before posting questions to stack overflow in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Its like using margins in this case it adds a dynamic margin-left based on column width.